# How to check Shared Library exposed functions in program

Tags: linux, shared-libraries

I am using a third party shared library and  I need to check whether a function is exported by shared library programatically.

How to do this. I need this because if function does not exist I need to run some other function locally.

Comment: Try `nm -C -D | grep -F ' T '` if you are using a shell script, and the `dlopen`, `dlsym` and `dlclose` functions in C/C++. Otherwise, please specify at least what programming language you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably use [dlsym](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlsym) for this.

If you load the library with dlopen, you will use the handle that it returns.

If you're linked against this library you may use special pseudo-handles (10x to caf for pointing it out):

*From dlsym man:*

> There are two special pseudo-handles, RTLD_DEFAULT and RTLD_NEXT. The former will find the first occurrence of the desired symbol using the default library search order. The latter will find the next occurrence of a function in the search order after the current library. This allows one to provide a wrapper around a function in another shared library.

Comment: On Linux you don't need to open it with `dlopen()` - if the target library is linked against the main program, you can pass the pseudo-handle `RTLD_DEFAULT` to `dlsym()`.

Answer (score 1):

may be you can use objdump command to check all symbol exposed like this
objdump -T libtest.so

Answer (score 0):

Check the header file of the intended library to get the function signature.
Using [dlopen](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dlopen.html) you can load the library dynamically and fetch the symbol if it is exposed in the library with subsequent calls to dlsym and dlclose.